# How do I reset corrupted pcDuino to its initial state?

Tags: lubuntu, arduino

I updated Lubuntu 12.04 in pcDuino v1, but it was my mistake, since it is not capable of running versions beyond 12.04. After that it crashed and I restarted pcDuino and it stopped here showing the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't really "crashed", I can't even see a *Kernel Panic* or something similar. But as I face a lot of problems with that *Allwinner* CPU crap myself (pcDuino v1 here), here are some options that might enable you to help yourself:

1. Put the device on your network via Ethernet to have a stable connection. Try to SSH into your pcDuino. Use `arp -a` on your network (on some other device) to see the IPs and Mac-addresses of all connected devices. If you can't identify the pcDuino, you might want to log into your routers GUI via some browser and check the IP. Then just use `ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.1` using the IP your network. If you don't know it, you can get your own Gateway IP address via for e.g. `route -n get default` on OS X, via `ipconfig`, `ifconfig`, etc. You can then perform a IP range scan using for e.g. *nmap* with `nmap -sP 192.168.0.2-254`. The default password is `ubuntu`. You can try to fix your APT packages if some are broken with `sudo apt-get -f install` for e.g. **Additional note:** If that works, you might want to generate a SSH key pair, add it to the keychain. More about that [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) on this GitHub tutorial.
2. If that does not work, you can generate a new Kernel SD-Card (see this lame tutorial on [linksprite](http://learn.linksprite.com/pcduino/quick-start/steps-to-flash-ubuntu-images-to-pcduino/), which should be enough) and a new USB-stick containing the OS to flash it.  **Additional note:** In case you encounter a `env` and `bash not found` error, just change the *shebang* in the `update.sh` file to `#!/bin/sh` which is enough to get the OS installation running.

Sidenote: I managed to put Lubuntu 14.04 on it about a year ago, but it then ran out of space, so this really is not recommended.